# rvest how to get data between id span

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to use the rvest package to get a value placed between a span class id and div. The html code looks like this:

```
library(rvest)

doc <- '<div id="economicCurrentTime" class="ecoCurrentTime ">
<span class="grayClockIcon">&nbsp;</span>Current Time:
<span id="currentTime" class="bold blackFont" data-datetime="2023/09/01 19:27:02">19:27</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span id="timeZoneGmtOffsetFormatted">(GMT -4:00)</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span class="dropDownArrowGray"></span> </div>'
```

I want to collect the value "(GMT -4:00)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the xpath (or css) and select the only the "span" nodes where the id is equal to "timeZoneGmtOffsetFormatted".

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

h <- read_html(doc)
html_elements(h, xpath='.//span[@id="timeZoneGmtOffsetFormatted"]') %>%
             html_text()
#or
#html_elements(h, 'span[id="timeZoneGmtOffsetFormatted"]') %>% html_text()
#[1] "(GMT -4:00)"
```

Here is a good reference: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/wp-content/uploads/imported/1269-Locators_groups_1_0_2.pdf?file=4938

Comment: Thank you very much @Dave2e. I run your suggestion into my actual application and I get as result: character(0) . I updated the post, to provide the actual URL. I wonder if I missed an upper node?

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e. This suggested code works.